# How can I get a value from a method I called? C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, innerhtml

I want to get the value of the a string from the method I called so I will be able to create a list using InnerHtml.

Here is an example code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //MailBorrow();
    int count = 0;
    string[] names = new string[30];
    SqlCommand cmdgetnames = new SqlCommand("SELECT Distinct[names] FROM Employees", MyConN);
    using (SqlDataReader ReadeR = cmdgetnames.ExecuteReader())
        while (ReadeR.Read())
        {
            names[count] = ReadeR[0].ToString();
            count++;
        }
    foreach (string person in names)
    {
        Method(person);
        Sample.InnerHtml += **INEEDTHISBACK**;
    }
}
private void Method(string person)
{
    string html = "<h2>"+ person +",</h2>";
    SqlCommand cmdgetforPM = new SqlCommand("SELECT [tools] FROM Equipment WHERE owner = '" + person + "'", MyConN);
    using (SqlDataReader ReadeR = cmdgetforPM.ExecuteReader())
        while (ReadeR.Read())
        {
           html+= "<p>"+ Reader[tools].ToString() +"</p><br />"
        }
    **INEEDTHISBACK** = html;
}
```

I new here, please give me some advise if you think my coding is bad.
Thanks! :-)

Comment: Another wonderful example how to mix together the data, business and presentation layers. I have goosebumps when I see html and SQL in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? Change the return type to `string` and return the value that you have generated. Few more things that you have to note here is,

- The SQL query execution :- You have choose the worst method for executing the query. Make use of parameterization for executing such concatenated queries.
- Make use of `StringBuilder` instead for string

The modified method will looks like the following:

```
private string Method(string person)
{
    StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    string querySql ="SELECT [tools] FROM Equipment WHERE owner = @person"; 
    using (SqlCommand cmdSql = new SqlCommand(querySql, conObject))
    {
        cmdSql.Parameters.Add("@person", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = person;
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdSql.ExecuteReader())
        {               
            htmlBuilder.Append("<h2>"+ person +",</h2>");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                htmlBuilder.Append("<p>"+ reader[tools].ToString() +"</p><br />");
            }
        }
     }
     return htmlBuilder.ToString();
}
```

In the Calling method also you can use stringBuilder instead for string, and hence avoid continuous modification of innetHtml text. Changes in the calling method like this:

```
StringBuilder innerHtml = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string person in names)
{        
    innerHtml.Append(Method(person));
}
Sample.InnerHtml = innerHtml.ToString();
```

Comment: I can make the post better, if the downvoter able to specify the reason for the vote

Comment: Kind of odd that you first mention using `StringBuilder` and right below all that you fill InnerHtml using string concat in a loop.

Comment: @Corak -  Nyerguds: Thanks for spotting the mistakes, made changes in the post

Answer (score 0):

First change signature of your method to return string

```
 private string Method(string person)
    {
        string html = "<h2>"+ person +",</h2>";
        SqlCommand cmdgetforPM = new SqlCommand("SELECT [tools] FROM Equipment WHERE owner = '" + person + "'", MyConN);
        using (SqlDataReader ReadeR = cmdgetforPM.ExecuteReader())
            while (ReadeR.Read())
            {
               html+= "<p>"+ Reader[tools].ToString() +"</p><br />"
            }
        return html;
    }
```

then use it:

```
Sample.InnerHtml += Method(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could pass it into another method?

```
Class.MyMethod(html);
```

Your method:

```
public static string MyMethod(string input)
{
    // do whatever here
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods have a return type. Currently your Method uses `void`, which means nothing. Replace that with `string` and return the html with the `return` keyword.

Please read the following documentation on the return keyword in C#.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to use an out parameter.